# How to make \note{...} to show current frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I am preparing slides for a large presentation using the beamer class.
In the beginning I write

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

\begin{document}
% a LOT of frames
\end{document}
```

Only for very few slides I need to see notes on the secondary screen. For the rest of them, however, I would like to see the current frame in full size on the secondary screen, instead of an empty screen with a small version of the frame at the upper-right corner of the screen. This should be done preferably by default, without the need to write a `\note{...}` command on each frame (but if I have to, I will do it...). How can I make this behavior the default?

Note: I am aware that I can paste the content of the frame inside the `\note`, but this is of course a terrible solution

Comment: I think that `pgfpages` lets you switch page layouts mid document so I'd look at the documentation for that first just to see what might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

To get a copy of the current frame in the note, you can use `\insertslideintonotes{1}`. The number determines the scaling.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title Page
\begin{frame}[t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
%
Here's a slide.
\note{\insertslideintonotes{1}}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
%
Here's a slide.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]